# How to remove a value from a list in python when the user specifies which one they want to remove

Tags: python, list

For instance, if I had this to start:

```
Movies = [["Sixth sense"],["Austin Powers 2"],["Ted"],["Lethal weapon"],["Paul"],["Die hard"],["Kick ass"],["Avengers"],["I am legend"],["Matrix"]]
Choice = int(input("Which movie do you want to see?"))
print (Movies[Choice])
```

How would I ask the user to remove the film they didn't like?

Comment: Why is Movies a list of lists of strings, rather than just a list of strings?

Comment: You're only going to require a list of strings, not a list of lists... Also, you should probably explain more? Do they have to pick a number... How do they know what number relates to which movie etc... etc... What exactly is your assignment? Is the above your entire code, or do you have a specific problem you're not able to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
Movies = [["Sixth sense"],["Austin Powers 2"],["Ted"],["Lethal weapon"],["Paul"],["Die hard"],["Kick ass"],["Avengers"],["I am legend"],["Matrix"]]
```

I'll assume that they chose #4 (they're choosing a number, so I'm assuming deletion by index),

```
Choice = 4
```

Note that the 4<sup>th</sup> item isn't `'Paul'` but `['Paul']`:

```
Movies[4]
#>>> ['Paul']
```

You can just delete at that index

```
del Movies[4]

Movies
#>>> [['Sixth sense'], ['Austin Powers 2'], ['Ted'], ['Lethal weapon'], ['Die hard'], ['Kick ass'], ['Avengers'], ['I am legend'], ['Matrix']]
```